# Удаление элементов и узлов из TreeView и модели

Tags: javafx

Здравствуйте.
Есть задание: считать из xml данные, отобразить их в виде дерева и сделать операции добавления/удаления элементов и узлов, затем экспортировать в xml.
Нужно проделать это на XML следующего вида:

```
<groups>
<group name="ГР1">
    <students>
        <student head="true">
            <surname>Аверьянов</surname>
            <name>Игорь</name>
            <middleName>Анатольевич</middleName>
            <rating>100</rating>
        </student>
    </students>
</group>
<group name="ГР2">
    <students>
        <student head="false">
            <surname>Базаров</surname>
            <name>Андрей</name>
            <middleName>Викторович</middleName>
            <rating>71</rating>
        </student>
    </students>
</group>
<group name="ГР3">
    <students>
        <student head="false">
            <surname>Васильев</surname>
            <name>Максим</name>
            <middleName>Викторович</middleName>
            <rating>54</rating>
        </student>
    </students>
</group>
```

Для парсинга я выбрал JAXB и, соответственно, подготовил для него классы.
Затем, беру данные и подготавливаю их для отображения в TreeView.
Проблема заключается в удалении выбранного в TreeView элемента. Из TreeView он удаляется, а из модели нет. Т.к. кода относительно много для вставки. [вот](https://github.com/nilke1995/jaxb)
репозиторий на github. Проблема заключается в классе DataForGUI в методе remove. я могу удалить группу, но как удалить студента не знаю

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны удалять не из Отображения (TreeView), а из модели, и тогда Отображение обновится автоматически.

Comment: дело в том, что мне нужно удалить именно выделенный элемент и он типа TreeItem, а модель хранится в объекте класса и я не совсем понимаю как связать TreeItem и объект класса

Comment: я вопрос не корректно сформулировал, он был именно в том, как удалить из модели

Comment: в методу remove класса DataForGUI у меня реализовано удаление групп, а как студентов удалять- не пойму

Comment: и на примере добавления(оно у меня работает корректно), при добавлении в модель отображение автоматически не обновляется

Comment: у вас не происходит добавление в модель. вы добавляете в Отображение.